# how to create a ListView from an ArrayList that comes from an intent in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

I want to have a ListView that shows the items in an ArrayList. This is my code, did I miss something?

```
        lvList = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
        ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
        lvList.setAdapter(adapter);
```